# click(function() button - how to toggle styles?

Tags: jquery

I hear from the comments that toggle does not fit here, so I removed it. The code below works...but is there a better way to do this...my Jquery is limited. Thank you.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.botColorBoxBtn1').click(function() {
        $("div.botColorBox").css({ 'height':'90px'});
        $('div.botColorBoxBtn1').hide();
        $('div.botColorBoxBtn2').show();return false;
});
});

$(document).ready(function(){
$('div.botColorBoxBtn2').click(function() {
        $("div.botColorBox").css({ 'height':'11px'});
        $('div.botColorBoxBtn2').hide();
        $('div.botColorBoxBtn1').show();return false;
});
});
```

Comment: [what do you expect `toggle` to do?](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: Are you using jQuery 1.9 or higher? If so, the [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/) you're looking for does not exist anymore.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi, I thought so too, but this doesn't implemention for the toggle-event doesn't make sense.

Comment: @gdoron, you're right, only one argument is passed. This looks like plain misuse of the method.

Comment: Sounds like toggle should not be used here I gather. I took it out and the button click expands the div below...but now how to click the button again and close it? The link posted above did not clear it up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the intended result, as [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) will show/hide the matched element.

Comment: This. You don't need that toggle there.

Comment: This what I was hoping for... http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_toggle_func